# Runnable as method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Why doesn't this code compile ? Unable to grasp nuances java method reference completely :(

```
public class TestClass {

    static void println() {}
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable r1 = () -> System.out::println; // compilation error
        Runnable r2 = () -> TestClass::println;  // compilation error
        Runnable r2 = () -> System.out.println("Hello World");  // This is fine !!

    }
}
```

Comment: what do the error messages tell you? you say "print" but you don't say what or how to print

Comment: Imagine it as "X.y" will accesses(execute) method `y` of `X` while `X::y` refers to(replicates) the execution of method `y` of `X`.

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of misunderstanding here, and other answers only provide final result. So here's a real explanation.

In java, there are lambdas (`() -> something`), and method references (`Class::method`). They're basically the same thing, just with different (shorter) syntax. You can mix lambdas and method references, if you'd like (lambda in a lambda, method reference in a lambda). As long as everything is a correct type, you're ok.

So `System.out::println` is a method reference of type `Consumer<String>`, cause `System.out.println()` takes `String` as argument, and returns `void` - that's `Consumer<String>`. (There is also `System.out.println()` that takes no arguments, in that case it'd be a `Runnable`)

`Runnable` is a bit different because it doesn't receive any argument or returns a value. Example could be `List::clear`.

As to why your code was a compilation error:

When declaring a `Runnable` as lambda, you have to receive no arguments and return `void`. This lambda: `Runnable r1 = () -> System.out::println;` doesn't match the criteria, because it does receive no arguments (`() ->`), but it's expression does return a type - `Consumer<String>` (or `Runnable` again), not a `void`. It could be a valid `Runnable` if you managed to return nothing, like

```
Runnable r1 = () ->  {
  Consumer<String> str1 = System.out::println; // either this
  Runnable str2 = System.out::println; // or this
  return; // return type - void
}
```

But that kinda doesn't make sense.

So you can see clearly, that `() -> System.out::println()` is actually a lambda that supplies `Runnable` or `Consumer<String>`, so it's type should be

```
Supplier<Runnable> s = () -> System.out::println; // either this
Supplier<Consumer<String>> s = () -> System.out::println; // or this
```

To use it directly, you'd just have to ditch the `Supplier<>`

```
Runnable s = System.out::println; // either this
Consumer<String> s = System.out::println; // or this
```

How about you just explain what you're trying to do, and we'll help you.

Comment: thanks for taking the effort of going in so much detail. It does clear things up for me. I made the mistake of mixing lamba expression with method reference, without understanding how method reference would be interpretted exactly at that point. 
Method reference in my case was returning a supplier while I was under the impression it would be executing and returning void.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a "direct" method reference, not a supplier of something represented by a method reference.

```
Runnable r1 = System.out::println;
Runnable r2 = TestClass::println;
```

Compare

```
Supplier<Runnable> a = () -> System.out::println;
```

with

```
Runnable b = System.out::println;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand my folly

Answer (score 0):

This is not how [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) work.
You use them like so:

```
Runnable r1 = System.out::println;
```

Comment: Even I get it wrong or the sentence above is incorrect. Actually `() -> System.out::println;` returns a `Supplier<Runnable>` and it works exactly as method references work...

Comment: Thanks, I understand my folly

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to write in this way:

```
Runnable r1 = System.out::println;
Runnable r2 = TestClass::println;
```

Here you can read more about method references https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Thanks, I understand my folly

Answer (score 0):

In this case, System.out.println is a consumer (It takes a String and does something with it)

```
    Consumer<String> c = System.out::println;
    
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Whee", "Boo");
    strings.forEach(c);  <-- We then pass this consumer here.
```

or without:

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Whee", "Boo");
   
    strings.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element)); <-- without method reference

    strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```